# Custom title bar behing pivot header

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

After the 1809 Windows 10 update, I have been running in some issues with my title bar being behind the pivot header. Something like on chrome where you have your tabs on top.

If I test this sample code in a Windows machine with 1803 update it works fine. But if it is running in a 1809 machine I cannot drag my app if the pivot is on top.

Here is the sample I've been using:
https://github.com/nikomac/CustomTitleBar

I modified the pivot style so I could reach the titlebar behind.

```
 <Style x:Key="PivotDefaultStyle"
           TargetType="Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">

...

<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              Background="{x:Null}"
              BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False"                                              
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center"

...
```

Those background property are the only modification I had to do to make it work in 1803.

Is there any way I could adjust this style or fix to make it work again?

Thank you.

Comment: Didn't 1809 get pulled entirely?

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes it did, but we expect it to be pushed again. And we usually update as soon as new updates are up so we can fix this kind of problems before our clients get them.

Comment: I have tested in Version 1809 OS build 18262.1000, it looks well and pivot item could be switch well.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT The problem is not to switch between the two pivot items. Is to drag from the green title bar the entire app. Is the drag working well? If it does we just need to wait for the update, currently i run in 1809 - 17763.55.

Comment: Drag the pivot item only works in touch model, have you ever done it with mouse?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes, I do my tests with mouse, the problem is i cannot drag the entire app (because the titlebar is behind the pivot headers, but there is still space after the headers, something like edge when you have 2 o 3 tabs open and you can drag the entire window) not a single item, I solved my problem using toolkit TabView insted of a Pivot. Thank you.